# How to make Xcode correctly find the headers, using the “User headers search paths”?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios, frameworks, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build a framework from libFLAC with Xcode, to use within my own Mac OS X application.

I use these FLAC sources:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flac/files/flac-src/flac-1.2.1-src/flac-1.2.1.tar.gz/download

I only need a few of these source files but I'd rather keep everything untouched so I'm able to keep the original FLAC source if I want to I distribute the framework project with my own sources.

The flac-1.2.1.tar.gz contains these directories:

```
flac-1.2.1/include/
flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/
flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/include/
```

In order to build libFLAC, I've added the .c files from 'flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC' into the project (as references). I also added the .h files.

The headers used in the source code are located in:

```
flac-1.2.1/include/FLAC/
flac-1.2.1/include/share/
flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/private/
```

For instance the sources code calls for the header are:

```
#include "private/bitmath.h"
#include "FLAC/assert.h"
#include "private/bitwriter.h"
#include "private/crc.h"
#include "share/alloc.h"
```

etc.

In Xcode, I've added these 'User Header Search Paths' to the the target Build Settings:

```
$(SRCROOT)/flac-1.2.1/include/
$(SRCROOT)/flac-1.2.1/src/libFLAC/include/
```

And of course, I've placed my flac-1.2.1 directory in the right place.

When I want to compile, the compiler doesn't find the headers file. I tried with GCC 4.2 and LLVM compiler 2.0. What am I doing wrong? Should I do something more?

I'm new into importing C sources in my otherwise all-ObjC project and I'd be happy to try whatever you throw at me. Just please avoid answering "If you can't do it, you shouldn't do it". I need to learn this and I will.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have the answer, it was really dumb. My Xcode Project folder path itself was containing a space character. The compiler doesn't like that ;)

Comment: I'm having trouble using libFlac in an iOS project. Do you have your libFLAC framework available for download anywhere?